# get startdate and enddate from specified week of the month

Tags: sql-server-2008, date

I need to find start date and end date from specified (1/2/3/4/5) week of month. So that I can get the records where Date_Created comes in specified (1/2/3/4/5) Week.

For example if

```
I choose 1st week of febuary 2013 then 
I want startdate = 2/1/2013 and enddate = 2/2/2013
I choose 2nd week of febuary 2013 then 
I want startdate = 2/3/2013 and enddate = 2/9/2013
```

and similary for rest weeks.

I have SQL Server 2008 at Database Side. If anyone have Idea then Please Share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a query to get all weeks start and end dates for given month. So you can select from this query week you need:

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/9211)

```
with C(i) as 
( select CAST('2013-02-01' as datetime) i
  UNION ALL
  select DATEADD (day,1,i) i from C 
    where DATEADD (day,1,i)
          <DATEADD(month,1,'2013-02-01')
), C1 as
(
select DATEPART(WEEK,i)-DATEPART(WEEK,'2013-02-01')+1 WeekOfMonth,i from C
)
select WeekOfMonth,min(i) StartDate, max(i) EndDate from C1 group by WeekOfMonth
```

Comment: Thankx. This Answer helped me. Its short code and after some modification in this I created a procedure which inputs week no and outputs first and last day of week.

Comment: +1 Wow, that's a nice solution, `DATEPART(WEEK,i)-DATEPART(WEEK,'2013-02-01')` and `GROUP BY` with `MIN` and `MAX` are really cleverly used here.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a procedure to solve my problem which will take week no(1/2/3/4/5) as input and will return startdate and enddate

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.SPGetStartAndEndDateofSpcifiedWeek
    @Week int
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON 
    DECLARE @date DateTime
    DECLARE @currdate DateTime
    DECLARE @startdate DateTime
    DECLARE @enddate DateTime
    DECLARE @CurrWeek int

    /*SET @date  = CONVERT(date,GETDATE())*/
    SET @currdate  = CONVERT(date,GETDATE())
    SET @CurrWeek = datediff(week, dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0)), 0), GETDATE() - 1) + 1

    IF (@Week = 1)
    BEGIN
        IF (@CurrWeek = 1)
        BEGIN SET @date = @currdate END
        IF (@CurrWeek = 2)
        BEGIN SET @date = @currdate - 7 END
        IF (@CurrWeek = 3)
        BEGIN SET @date = @currdate - 14 END
        IF (@CurrWeek = 4)
        BEGIN SET @date = @currdate - 21 END
        IF (@CurrWeek = 5)
        BEGIN SET @date = @currdate - 28 END
    END
    IF (@Week = 2)
    BEGIN
        IF (@CurrWeek = 1)
        BEGIN SET @date = @currdate + 7 END
        IF (@CurrWeek = 2)
        BEGIN SET @date = @currdate  END
        IF (@CurrWeek = 3)
        BEGIN SET @date = @currdate - 7 END
        IF (@CurrWeek = 4)
        BEGIN SET @date = @currdate - 14 END
        IF (@CurrWeek = 5)
        BEGIN SET @date = @currdate - 21 END
    END
    IF (@Week = 3)
    BEGIN
        IF (@CurrWeek = 1)
        BEGIN SET @date = @currdate + 14 END
        IF (@CurrWeek = 2)
        BEGIN SET @date = @currdate + 7 END
        IF (@CurrWeek = 3)
        BEGIN SET @date = @currdate END
        IF (@CurrWeek = 4)
        BEGIN SET @date = @currdate - 7 END
        IF (@CurrWeek = 5)
        BEGIN SET @date = @currdate - 14 END
    END
    IF (@Week = 4)
    BEGIN
        IF (@CurrWeek = 1)
        BEGIN SET @date = @currdate + 21 END
        IF (@CurrWeek = 2)
        BEGIN SET @date = @currdate + 14 END
        IF (@CurrWeek = 3)
        BEGIN SET @date = @currdate + 7 END
        IF (@CurrWeek = 4)
        BEGIN SET @date = @currdate END
        IF (@CurrWeek = 5)
        BEGIN SET @date = @currdate - 7 END
    END
    IF (@Week = 5)
    BEGIN
        IF (@CurrWeek = 1)
        BEGIN SET @date = @currdate + 28 END
        IF (@CurrWeek = 2)
        BEGIN SET @date = @currdate + 21 END
        IF (@CurrWeek = 3)
        BEGIN SET @date = @currdate + 14 END
        IF (@CurrWeek = 4)
        BEGIN SET @date = @currdate + 7 END
        IF (@CurrWeek = 5)
        BEGIN SET @date = @currdate END
    END

    Select  CONVERT(date, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, @date), - 1)) as startdate,
               CONVERT(date, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, @date), 5)) as enddate

    RETURN
```

Answer (score 1):

I modified code given by Valex to get the exact output as I required.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SPReturnStartEndDateOfSpecifiedWeek
    @Week int,
    @P_startdate DateTime OUTPUT,
    @P_enddate DateTime OUTPUT
AS
    /* SET NOCOUNT ON */

    with C(i) as 
    ( 
      select CAST((DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) as datetime) i
      UNION ALL
      select DATEADD (day,1,i) i from C 
      where DATEADD (day,1,i)<DATEADD(month,1,(DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), 0)))
    ), 
    C1 as
    (
      select DATEPART(WEEK,i)-DATEPART(WEEK,(DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), 0)))+1 WeekOfMonth,i from C
    ),
    C2 as
    (
        select WeekOfMonth,min(i) StartDate, max(i) EndDate from C1 group by WeekOfMonth
    )

    Select  @P_startdate = StartDate,
            @P_enddate = EndDate  
    from C2
    WHERE WeekOfMonth=@Week 

RETURN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to get the start or end date for the week. Just provide a date for which you find the dates.

Logic is quite simple just get the start and end date of the week and then check if the start date is greater than the month date if so take the month date as the week start date else the start date of the week.

Fiddle a bit to get what you want 
Here is the code:

```
DECLARE @date datetime
SET @date = '2013-01-30'
DECLARE @startdate datetime
DECLARE  @enddate datetime
DECLARE @MonthStart datetime
Declare @MonthEnd datetime

SET @startdate = DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, @date), 6) 
SET @enddate =  DATEADD(dd,6, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, @date), 6))
SET @monthStart = CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(@date)-1),@date),101)
SET @MonthEnd =CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,@date))),DATEADD(mm,1,@date)),101)

--select @startdate wstart,@MonthStart monthstart,@enddate wend,@MonthEnd monthend
select  
[date] =  @date
,[week] = DATEPART(wk,@date)
,[WeekStartDate] = Case
                        WHEN @startdate <= @MonthStart then @MonthStart else @startdate  
                    END
,[WeekEndDate] = Case
                        WHEN @enddate > @MonthEnd then @MonthEnd else @enddate   
                    END
```

see here:

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/9188)

Comment: thankx for your reply but I want startdate and endate on entering week no not a date.

Comment: how do you wish to enter the week?
This can also be done easily. Can you provide a sample format of your input value. Like "1-2" for 1st week of 2nd month?... the logic is given now its just a matter of tweaking the code a bit.

Comment: Input will be  1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5. and output will be startdate and enddate of respective week. this all will consider current month. for example for 2 week of current month startdate will be 2/3/2013 and enddate will be 2/9/2013

Comment: you mean to say if you only want the week then for the 2nd week of feb you will input 5901? 
or else you have to specify the year and the month with the week. correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: you are misunderstanding the things... I want to take only week no from user as input... that clearly means input will be 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 ... and in code i will consider current month and year from current date.